What is the Resolution and Frame Rate/Bitrate limitation for VP8 Codec
As per the documentation of VP9 Codec in Wikipedia VP9 has the concept of Profile and Level. Based on these profiles and levels it also has some limitations on Resolution/Frame Rate/ Bitrate as follows,

Here I get the concept clearly.
So now I want to know about the limitations of VP8 Codec. How/Where I can find this? (Not found in the Wikipedia documentation)

The maximum resolution VP8 supports is 16383x16383 with no limit on framerate or bitrate.
According to https://www.webmproject.org/about/faq/#vp8-and-vp9-video-codecs

VP8 uses 14 bits for width and height, for a maximum resolution of 16383x16383 pixels.
VP9 uses 16 bits for width and height, for a maximum resolution of 65536x65536 pixels.
Neither VP9 nor VP8 places any restriction on framerate or datarate.

